# ConstraintLayout: layout_constrainedHeight="true" makes my View too small to wrap content

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to make a layout where the user reads some text, and then types in an `EditText`. The text should fill the available space as much as possible, while always showing the `EditText` and `Button`.

When the user clicks the `EditText`, and the keyboard opens, the `TextView` should resize and allow the user to scroll the text.

I have almost achieved this using Constraint Layout chains, as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/somelayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/explanationText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="@string/sometext"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/emailInput"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_max="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailInput"
    style="@style/email_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:hint="@string/onboarding_user_email_hint"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/saveButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/explanationText"
    tools:ignore="Autofill" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveButton"
    style="@style/raised_button_grey"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:width="127dp"
    android:text="@string/save"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When the user opens the keyboard, the `TextView` indeed shrinks to fill the available space, and the text becomes scrollable. Great!

However, there's one small bug. Even when the `TextView` has plenty of space to fill, it doesn't wrap content - the height of the `TextView` is always 1 or 2 lines too small, forcing the text to scroll.

It seems like the `ConstraintLayout` isn't measuring the height of the content of the `TextView` exactly right, so the `TextView` is just too short to properly `wrap_content`. Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: I have similar bug. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, sadly I never found a solution

Comment: `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` will reduce the size of a view according to it's constraints. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61826350/7210237

Comment: Try setting `android:layout_height="0dp"` ("MATCH_CONSTRAINT"), i.e. match to the top & bottom constraints. In this situation, `wrap_content` height seems to cause problems like making the auto-text not grow the size back when the content gets shorter. Also, `layout_constraintHeight_max="0dp"` looks incorrect -- that should set the max height to 0.