# ConstraintLayout hides the last line of TextView with app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack

I have noticed weird behavior of `ConstraintLayout` (version 1.1.3) that hides the last line of `TextView` whenever I try to use height with `wrap_content` property and `layout_constrainedHeight` is set to `true`.

With `layout_constrainedHeight`:

[image: First image]

With no `layout_constrainedHeight`:

[image: Second image]

Source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem..."
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I thought that whenever I want to use `wrap_content` with `ConstraintLayout` I have to set `layout_constrainedHeight` to true, but this sometimes gives me weird bugs. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

If I remove the margin around `TextView`, it works fine. It seems that `ConstraintLayout` does something wrong with `wrap_content` and margins.

Comment: I can confirm this. It has happened to me, and the solution consisted in having to re-think the layout. You should file an [issue at google's tracker for ConstraintLayout](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:323867%20status:open)

Comment: Upgrade your layout to `implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta6"`

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#wrap_content-:-enforcing-constraints-added-in-1.1):

> WRAP_CONTENT : enforcing constraints (Added in 1.1)
>
> If a dimension is set to WRAP_CONTENT, in versions before 1.1 they will be treated as a literal dimension -- meaning, constraints will not limit the resulting dimension. 
>   While in general this is enough (and faster), in some situations, you might want to use WRAP_CONTENT, yet keep enforcing constraints to limit the resulting dimension. In that case, you can add one of the corresponding attribute:
>
> app:layout_constrainedWidth=”true|false”
>
> app:layout_constrainedHeight=”true|false”

I'll emphasise a piece of this quote:
**keep enforcing constraints to limit the resulting dimension**

So basically, setting `layout_constrainedHeight` or `layout_constrainedWidth` to `true` will preserve constraints and reduce view size by the specified margin instead of pushing all the other views around and increasing current view height/width to fit the content.

Here is an example with `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` and `app:layout_constrainedWidth=”true”` and different margins. Red `TextView` wrapped it's content and after that was reduced in size. Green `TextView` has no `app:layout_constrained...="true"` attributes and margins set. Their height is equal, but the width is different in the end.

[image: Example with different margins]

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="86dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
        android:background="#ff2356"
        android:text="@string/lorem_kind_of"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"


        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"/> <!-- This line is the only difference -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="86dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
        android:background="#009900"
        android:text="@string/lorem_kind_of"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_text_view" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My guess is that you probably do not need to use `app:layout_constrainedHeight` attribute. You are welcome to leave a comment and we will elaborate on this further if my answer doesn't solve your problem.

### UPDATE (22 May 2020)

Looks like the behaviour that you want is achievable only without the `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"`. I may be wrong, it depends on the final desired result, but according to my "experiments" looks like `app:layout_constrainedHeight` constraints a view from growing further it's minimum size.

I've updated the XML code and recorded [a little video](https://youtu.be/nLotEkiKDEQ) to see the difference.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand what I have written, but the problem is that there are no height limitations in this example. `TextView` can stretch its height without any obstacles. I updated the images.

Comment: @Nominalista, I've updated the answer. Looks like there is a height limitation and it is equal to (minimum view height w/o margins + paddings). Then margins values are subtracted from this value giving you the view that is cut at the end with the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one more constraint for bottom of your `TextView` - `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` or `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/someOtherView"` and this `someOtherView` should have bottom constraint to the parent. There should be a vertical chain in order `app:layout_constrainedHeight` to work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Adding constraint to bottom of parent doesn't resolve this issue unfortunately.